# Smart diff algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, diff, uglifyjs

I am working with some javascript files and I am trying to write a new tool which looks at 2 uglified js source files and tells the difference like a diff tool but since uglified javascript is just one big line of symbols I cannot use the normal diff. I am not sure where to start to split the symbols or if there is already such a tool implemented?

I would very much appreciate any feedback. Thank you

Comment: How about using 2 tools? One to indent the source code and one to check differences?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8601029/120163

Comment: substitute semicolons ';' to newline chars '\n' - I think, it can help you.